# Trying to find the percent of total by Dividing SUM() by COUNT(), but it returns the value 1 - how can I better write my query?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the percent of a total with SQL. My SELECT statement looks like this:

```
SELECT 
  test_assignment,  
  count(distinct item_id) as num_items,
  SUM(view_binary) as total_views,
  SUM(view_binary_30) as binary_30_day
```

and produces a table like this

```
test_assignment num_items tot_views binary_30_day
0                1130      110247   1913
1                1068      104102   1860
```

I'm trying to add in a line that thats the binary_30_day sum, and divides it by the item count (so 1913/1130, 1860/1068)

I've tried (SUM(view_binary_30)/COUNT(DISTINCT item_id)) but it always returns 1 for both

How can I edit my Query do that I can create a column that will return the sum of my 30 day binary divided by the total number of items?

Comment: 1) tag question with proper database, 2) post a [mcve] including table definition and sample data, and a complete SQL statement

Comment: You should be lucky you don't get a divide by zero exception ;)

Comment: Probably Views is an integer and `int / int` is an integer division in your DBMS.

Comment: Just a hint to try a few things: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8195d78fe10d50ba6809186aacfd1840 I don't want to write an answer because your situation is too unclear, but maybe this helps.

Comment: Either cast the datatype to decimal or multiply the sum and count by 1.0 to force non-integer math

Answer (score 0):

AS @serg mentioned above, Please try converting either of Numerator or Denominator to decimal by multiplying with 1.0

```
SELECT
  test_assignment,
  COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) AS num_items,
  SUM(view_binary) AS total_views,
  SUM(view_binary_30) AS binary_30_day,
  SUM(view_binary_30) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) AS XYZ
```

Also if you encounter a divide by 0 error, then try converting the denominator to

```
CASE 
  WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) = 0 
    THEN NULL 
  ELSE COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) 
  END
```

If you are writing your script in bigquery then, you could simply use

```
SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(view_binary_30) * 1.0, COUNT(DISTINCT item_id)) AS XYZ
```

Comment: SUM(view_binary_30) * 1.0 worked perectly!

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I think you can now mark this as an accepted answer so that it can show

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the calculated don't exist until the select statement returns. You can use a sub query though and return your statistics.

```
SELECT  sub.test_assignment, sub.num_items, sub.total_views, sub.binary_30_day, 

(Cast(sub.binary_30_day as float) / sub.num_items) as rate
FROM (
SELECT 
  test_assignment,
  count(distinct item_id) as num_items,
  SUM(view_binary) as total_views,
  SUM(view_binary_30) as binary_30_day
) sub
```

Might wont to add a case when to deal with dividing by zero.

Comment: You don't know if this is the problem. Your propose will produce the same issue, too if the columns are defined as int.